# how to covert float value into integer in Y-Axis of MP android chart in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

**I am using MP chart to display trip count, everything is working fine except that the the Y-axis values are displaying as a floating value instead of Integer.**

I have integer value in jan,feb,etc... and I want to display it in y axis as integer format but it displays as float values, for ex. jan =10 and it has been converted into 10.0.

This is the code I am using:

```
//Variables

var barData: BarData? = null
    var barDataSet: BarDataSet? = null
    var barEntries: java.util.ArrayList<BarEntry>? = null
    var jan =""
    var feb=""
    var mar=""
    var apr=""
    var may=""
    var jun=""
    var jul=""
    var aug=""
    var sep=""
    var oct=""
    var nov=""
    var dec=""

//Method to call at OnCreate
private fun getEntries() {
        barEntries = java.util.ArrayList<BarEntry>()
        myUID = userSP.getString("userId")
        myUID?.let {
            db.collection("OperatorUsers").document(it)
                    .collection("Completed Services").document(myUID!!).addSnapshotListener { value: DocumentSnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException? ->
                        try {
                            if (value!!.exists()) {
                                jan = value.getLong("january").toString()
                                feb = value.getLong("february").toString()
                                mar = value.getLong("march").toString()
                                apr = value.getLong("april").toString()
                                may = value.getLong("may").toString()
                                jun = value.getLong("june").toString()
                                jul = value.getLong("july").toString()
                                aug = value.getLong("august").toString()
                                sep = value.getLong("september").toString()
                                oct = value.getLong("october").toString()
                                nov = value.getLong("november").toString()
                                dec = value.getLong("december").toString()
                                setBarChart()
                            }
                        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                            Log.d("fs", e.message!!)
                            setBarChart()
                        }
                    }
        }
    }

private fun setBarChart() {
        if (jan != "null") {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(1f, jan.toFloat()))
        } else {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(1f, 0.0f))
        }
        if (feb != "null") {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(2f, feb.toFloat()))
        } else {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(2f, 0.0f))
        }
        if (mar != "null") {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(3f, mar.toFloat()))
        } else {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(3f, 0.0f))
        }
        if (apr != "null") {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(4f, apr.toFloat()))
        } else {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(4f, 0.0f))
        }
        if (may != "null") {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(5f, may.toFloat()))
        } else {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(5f, 0.0f))
        }
        if (jun != "null") {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(6f, jun.toFloat()))
        } else {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(6f, 0.0f))
        }
        if (jul != "null") {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(7f, jul.toFloat()))
        } else {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(7f, 0.0f))
        }
        if (aug != "null") {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(8f, aug.toFloat()))
        } else {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(8f, 0.0f))
        }
        if (sep != "null") {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(9f, sep.toFloat()))
        } else {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(9f, 0.0f))
        }
        if (oct != "null") {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(10.0f, oct.toFloat()))
        } else {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(10.0f, 0.0f))
        }
        if (nov != "null") {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(11f, nov.toFloat()))
        } else {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(11f, 0.0f))
        }
        if (dec != "null") {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(12f, dec.toFloat()))
        } else {
            barEntries?.add(BarEntry(12f, 0.0f))
        }
        val labels = arrayOf("Dummy", "Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May",
                "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
        val xAxis: XAxis = mpBarChart.xAxis
        val leftAxis : YAxis = mpBarChart.axisLeft

        xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels)
        xAxis.granularity = 1f
        xAxis.isGranularityEnabled = true
        leftAxis.setGranularity(1.0f);
        leftAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true); // Required to enable granularity


        barDataSet = BarDataSet(barEntries, "No.of Trips")
        barData = BarData(barDataSet)
        mpBarChart.data=barData
        mpBarChart.description.text="Month wise Dashboard"
        barDataSet!!.setColors(*ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS)
        barDataSet!!.setValueTextSize(8f)
        barDataSet!!.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK)
        //mpBarChart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card_search)
        mpBarChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false)
        mpBarChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false)
        mpBarChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false)

    }
```

**I found many answers like value formatter but they are in java and I tried to converts it in Kotlin but it didn't help .
So please help anyone , Thanks in advance !**

Comment: what exactly have you tried? And what exactly did not work in those scenarios? How can we know what to tell you to do, if you don't tell us exactly what you need. For example, how would you convert `5.99`? Should it be `5` or `6` (we don't know you possible input)? Btw, you don't need those `if/else` statements, just do `barEntries?.add(BarEntry(1f, jan.toFloat() ?: 0.0f))`. Also what is the point for `barEntries` to be nullable in the first place? Initialise it as an empty list.

Comment: I have integer value in jan,feb,etc... and I want to display it in y axis as integer format but it displays as float values, for ex. jan =10 and it has been converted into 10.0.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the multiple issues with that code regarding null safety and lack of kotlin understanding, you can simply achieve this by removing unnecessary code.

1. You have a `DocumentSnapshot` that can give you a `Long`, and yet you transform that into a `String`
2. You then take that `String` and make it into something that you don't want, a `Float`.
3. The only reason you got to this predicament is because you are not handling the possibility of a `null` coming from `getFloat()`.

A `Long` is an integer, the only difference is that `Long` is a 64 bit integer and `Int` is a 32 bit integer, so you already had what you needed from the start.

```
var jan = 0L

//...//

value.getLong("january")?.let { jan = it }
//or
jan = value.getLong("january") ?: 0L

//...//

barEntries?.add(BarEntry(1f, jan))
```

I don't know what params the constructor of `BarEntry` can take, in the possibility that it can't take a `Float`, check the docs of the library you are using and change that `Long` into whatever it requires.